# how to convert dict element of dict to tuple and viceversa?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

```
{'a': { 1: -0.25, 2: -0.2}
 'b': {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}}
```

In above Dict how can i have convert it into form `{a:(-0.25,-0.2),b:('foo','bar')}` and vice versa.

Comment: How is the order of the values in the tuples supposed to be determined?

Comment: values has to be ordered as each element in dict and as we can see key is  `1` and `2` common ..

Comment: dicts don't have an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some sorting criterion to remain a meaningful order, as dicts don't have a real order. With numbers, the conversion and re-conversion should be quite reliable.

```
d = {'a': {1: -0.25, 2: -0.2},
     'b': {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}}

print("Original", d)

for k in d:
    d[k] = tuple(map(lambda x: x[1], sorted(d[k].items())))

print("Converted", d)

for k in d:
    d[k] = {i: elem for i, elem in enumerate(d[k], 1)}

print("Re-converted", d)
```

Output:

```
Original {'b': {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}, 'a': {1: -0.25, 2: -0.2}}
Converted {'b': ('foo', 'bar'), 'a': (-0.25, -0.2)}
Re-converted {'b': {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}, 'a': {1: -0.25, 2: -0.2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dic = {'a': { 1: -0.25, 2: -0.2}, 'b': {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}}
for key in dic:
    dic[key] = tuple(dic[key].values())
```

which outputs:

```
>>> dic
{'a': (-0.25, -0.2), 'b': ('foo', 'bar')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ToTupleDict(in_dict):  
  output = {}
  for item in in_dict:
    item_keys = in_dict[item].keys()
    item_keys.sort()
    item_list = []
    for k in item_keys:
      item_list.append(in_dict[item][k])
    output[item] = tuple(item_list)
  return output

def ToDictDict(in_dict):
  output = {}
  for item in in_dict:
    itemdict = {}
    for x in range(len(in_dict[item])):
      itemdict[x + 1] = in_dict[item][x]
    output[item] = itemdict
  return output

f = {'a': { 1: -0.25, 2: -0.2}, 'b': {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}}

g = ToTupleDict(f)
print "G: %s" % g
h = ToDictDict(g)
print "H: %s" % h
```

Sample output:

```
G: {'a': (-0.25, -0.2), 'b': ('foo', 'bar')}
H: {'a': {1: -0.25, 2: -0.2}, 'b': {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}}
```